# JS script doesn't work on wordpress site (changes nothing)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've approached a weird issue. I have this piece of code:

```
(function($){
    $("#maps1").hover(
      function(){$("#kontakt_os_1").hide();}
    );

    $("#maps2").hover(
      function(){$("#kontakt_os_2").hide();}
    );

    $("#maps3").hover(
      function(){$("#kontakt_os_3").hide();}
    );  
})(jQuery);
```

on jsfiddle as test, it works (when you will add necessary html code). when you will go to my test site:
https://www.flt-service.com.pl/kontakt/
[at the bottom; part with map; try to hover to elements with different background]

it is suppose to hide one of the tables on the left. BUt nothing is changing. why??

Comment: Didn't found you script on your test site. Probably, script doesn't work due to it absent

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance maybe the script is loaded in a bundled javascript file.

Comment: the script is loaded via script.js file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are loading this script in a bundled javascript file. So I've added your snippet in the console once the page was loaded. And it worked for me.

It seems your script is loaded before the full DOM is loaded. And I'll suggest two approaches:

- Try to add your script at the end of your html code. Just right before the `</body>` closing tag.
- Add your script inside a: `$(document).ready` function. It's not the best approach, but if it works with this, It can be a good starting point to debug your problem.

Comment: weird. did what you've mentioned and no progress ;/

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are named 'map1', 'map2' and 'map3' in the document. You call them 'map**s**1', 'map**s**2' and 'map**s**3' in your script. Change either to match and it should work.

```
(function($){
    $("#map1").hover(
      function(){$("#kontakt_os_1").hide();}
    );

    $("#map2").hover(
      function(){$("#kontakt_os_2").hide();}
    );

    $("#map3").hover(
      function(){$("#kontakt_os_3").hide();}
    );  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: naming is correct. I know it might be misleading but there are both elements like: map and maps

Comment: Where? Please review [this query](https://i.imgur.com/ErYP5nL.png) I made against your contact page.